# QTextEdit And QPushButton in one QAbstractModelItem

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qabstractitemmodel, qstyleditemdelegate

I use a QTreeView to visualize my objects properties. 
Its something like the Property Editor in the Qt Designer. I have every kind of values, bool, text, color values, enum, float, int, filenames etc.

I use a coustom model for holding all the object values and display it via a coustom delegate. So the delegate detects the kind of data and have special representation for editing, e.g. Spinboxes for int/float, and checkboxes for bool.
At the moment my Delegate creates editor for eg spinboxes AND override the paint() function for representing a value as checkbox.

Now i want to allow the user to edit a value in two ways. The user should use a normal textfield for edting, copy/paste, etc. to change the value or press a button for open the QFileDialog and select the correct file.
  It should look like this picture:

[image]

How can i achieve this?
I need a textfield AND a button to open the QFileDialog.

I use Qt 5.0. Thx for help

Comment: Do you want the text field and button to be visible just whilst in the editing state, or for both display and editing?

Comment: In best cases both, display and editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to use a custom widget, you could create one in code like this in your delegate's `createEditor()` function/ Something along these lines:

```
QFrame *frame = new QFrame();
frame->setLayout( new QHBoxLayout() );
frame->layout()->addWidget( new QLineEdit() );
frame->layout()->addWidget( new QToolButton() );
return frame;
```

Or you could create a custom widget with designer and return one of those.

Comment: I imagined such a thing already. Then i try to implement this and stick to the stardelegate expample.  I don't know the QFrame before, i take a look at this class.